# Error:ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++

I have got following:

```
    wxIntPtr* value;
    CreateRegKey();
    if (regkeyexist) {
        if (regKey->HasValue("LoggingStatus")) {
            regKey->QueryValue("LoggingStatus", value);
            if (value == 1)
```

however i get the error as the c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: @Anonymous srsly? you expect that `value` will ever point to address `1`?

Comment: @Anonymous: That will force the code to compile, but won't make it behave sensibly.

Comment: OP was asking for removing error, so I told :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should compile, but I don't know if it's what you want:

```
...
if (*value == 1)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to compare an `int` with a `pointer`

If you are indeed trying to see if the `pointer` is `1`

```
if (value == (wxIntPtr*)(1))
```

Otherwise if you are trying to compare against a value *pointed to by `value`*

```
if (*value == 1)
```

Although I have no idea why you would want to do the first :)

**I think what you probably should be doing is the following:**

```
wxIntPtr value; // wxIntPtr on the stack
...
regKey->QueryValue("LoggingStatus", &value); // Pass by reference to modify.
        if (value == 1)
```

This is how most Windows programming is done, with API calls initializing values and structures that *you have instantiated yourself*. Chances are that when you pass `wxIntPtr* value` to the `QueryValue()`, it will trying and set the value of it like this:

```
QueryValue("LoggingStatus", &value) { *value = 1; } // For example.
```

In your situation, this will cause a crash when it tries to *dereference an **uninitialized pointer***.

Comment: i am getting the value from the registry