# comparison between pointer and int C++ ellipse

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char problem5(char alc[], char a, int *n);

int main() {


    char aloc1[]={ 'g','g','c','g','a','g','g','g','t','g'};
    int size=sizeof(aloc1)/sizeof(aloc1[0]);
    cout << aloc1 << endl;
    int nalc = problem5(aloc1, 'g' ,&size);
    cout << nalc  << endl;
    return 0;
}

char problem5(char alc[], char c, int *n){
    int a = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(alc[0]!=c){
            a++;
        }
    }
    int nalc[a];
    int b=0;
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if(alc[0]!=c){
            nalc[b]=alc[j];
            b++;
        }
    }
    *n=&a;
    return nalc;
}
```

why do I keep having errors at the two for loops of the problem5?
it says something like comparison between pointer and int.
how can i fix that while the argument n remains pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error:ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987524/erroriso-c-forbids-comparison-between-pointer-and-integer)

Comment: and there is another problem coming out...cannot initialize return object of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'char [a]'

Comment: Suggestion: Learn the basics of the language.

Comment: `int nalc[a];` Here you're trying to initialize an array with a non-compile-time-constant size. Which is not possible in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Use `*n` to access the value pointed by `n`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < *n; i++){
```

And to change the value pointed by `n` to be equal to `a`:

```
*n = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an address in a for-loop. Try dereferencing the pointer. and also post your exact error please.